# Why does this Expression not work inside the ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working my way through some AngularJS tutorials.  Alongside, I have made my small toy to further experiment.  I have found a situation where a expression works when outside a ng-repeat but wont work inside and I would like to understand why?

The template:

```
<div ng-controller="TodoController">

  <ul ng-init="detail = 0">
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
      <span>{{todo.text}}</span>

      <!-- This does not make the detaildiv appear -->
      <input class="btn" type="submit" value="dive1" ng-click="detail = 1">
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- This however will make the detaildiv appear -->
  <input type="submit" value="divein" ng-click="detail = 1">
  <p>Detail: {{detail}}</p>

  <div id="detaildiv" ng-show="detail === 1">
    <span>Some content</span>
    <input type="submit" value="diveout" ng-click="detail = 0">
  </div>
</div>
```

What is it about ng-repeat that stops this working, or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: use $parent `<input class="btn" type="submit" value="dive1" ng-click="$parent.detail = 1">`

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates a child scope, so the `detail` created outside `ng-repeat` is different that `detail` created inside `ng-repeat`

Comment: @HarishR This should be an answer. :)

Comment: Great. Not as obvious as I thought - I'll keep working on the tutorials :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

putting my comment as an answer.

basically ng-repeat creates a child scope hence the detail inside and outside of ng-repeat is not same.
to fix this you have to use $parent.

```
<ul ng-init="detail = 0">
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
      <span>{{todo.text}}</span>

      <!-- This does not make the detaildiv appear -->
      <input class="btn" type="submit" value="dive1" ng-click="detail = 1">
    </li>
  </ul>
```

but the best way to fix this would be `never use ng-model without dot`.

or even better start using `controller as` syntax.

both above options would avoid such issues.

Comment: Thanks - I understand that this code is in need of controller.